# Is there a way to do LINQ to SQL with MySQL for .NET Application?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to know if there's way to achieve LINQ to SQL today with MySQL database to generate a *dbml file?

I need the dbml file while running a MySQL database.I been going through a lot of old posts but didn't find the ideal solution.

I'm running .NET 4.7 with VS.

Comment: Use dapper , this is light weight ORM

Comment: Dapper doesn't provide Linq to Sql capablities.

Comment: I've been using Devart's dotconnect for mysql for about 2 years successfully. But appear to have hit a bug that causes it not to return from Linq calls. Support from them appears to be zero at the moment. Been waiting for 2 weeks for help. I know coronavirus is affecting companies, but I would expect a software company to have successfully moved staff to their homes and now capable of providing some form of support. Sorry this isn't a solution, but I just wanted to make you aware in case you end up with similar problems.

Answer (score 5):

Linq-to-SQL was a "proof-of-concept" project for showing off the power of Linq and C# - but it **only** supports SQL Server and has no extensibility capabilities - and it's been long deprecated, too.

You should check out either [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) which allows you to use Linq-to-Entities, or something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to access MySQL from .NET